# Ehcache always returns null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I'm using Ehcache 2.6.8 as part of a Spring Boot application as the second-level cache for Hibernate 4.3.11.  I have a JMX MBean that allows me to inspect the contents of the cache ([here if you are interested](https://github.com/kenwdelong/stability-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kendelong/util/ehcache/EhcacheExaminer.java)).

First, I use the CacheManager name to get a list of caches.  That works fine.  I can return the cache with `cacheManager.getEhcache(cacheName)`.  Then I call `cache.getKeys()`.  This works fine, the cacheName is "com.myapp.DomainObjectName" and the keys are listed as "com.myapp.DomainObjectName#1", "com.myapp.DomainObjectName#2", etc.

But then I try to access one of the objects, by calling `cache.get("com.myapp.DomainObjectName#1")`, using one of the keys that the cache itself told me was present.  Yet, the result is always null.

Why is that?  Why can I not find an object associated with a key that the cache itself, just moments before, said was present?

PS, probably not relevant, but I'm using JGroups to distribute the cache in production.  However, I see the same behavior even on my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you can find keys indicate that there is content in your cache.

From reading your question, you are wrongly interpreting the keys as being `String`I believe. What JMX shows you is the `toString()` of the key and thus using that `String` as the key returns you nothing.

You need a way to use directly the object in the `get(key)`.

Comment: D'oh! For whatever reason I was assuming the keys were Strings, without thinking about it.  Thanks!